# Extracting food items from sentences

Tags: algorithm, nlp

Given a sentence:

> I had peanut butter and jelly sandwich and a cup of coffee for
>   breakfast

I want to be able to extract the following food items from it:

**peanut butter and jelly sandwich**

**coffee**

Till now, using POS tagging, I have been able to extract the individual food items, i.e.

**peanut, butter, jelly, sandwich, coffee**

But like I said, what I need is **peanut butter and jelly sandwich** instead of the individual items.

Is there some way of doing this without having a corpus or database of food items in the backend?

Comment: Why do you want _coffee_ and not _cup of coffee_ ? Seems like that would be more consistent..

Comment: *cup of coffee* is also fine. In fact that is my ultimate aim (to capture the quantity as well). However, right now I am stuck on the above problem.

Comment: Without knowing (or learning) what combinations are "a thing", it's difficult to decide whether "X and Y" is a single food item or not.

Comment: It's pretty difficult because even a correct english sentence can be ambiguous: "I like peanut butter and jelly sandwiches." ... Do you like peanut butter jelly sandwiches or do you like peanut butter sandwiches and jelly sandwiches?

Comment: Can't it be done with *keyword extrataction* using `RAKE` in python or `KEA` in java. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume22/erkan04a-html/erkan04a.html

Answer (score 10):

You can attempt it without using a trained set which contains a corpus of food items, but the approach shall work without it too.

Instead of doing simple POS tagging, do a dependency parsing combined with POS tagging.
That way would be able to find relations between multiple tokens of the phrase, and parsing the dependency tree with restricted conditions like noun-noun dependencies you shall be able to find relevant chunk.

You can use [spacy for dep parsing](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/dependency-parse). Here is output from displacy :

https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/?text=peanut%20butter%20and%20jelly%20sandwich%20is%20delicious&model=en&cpu=1&cph=1

[image]

[image]

- You can use freely available data here, or something better:
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_foods as a training set to
  create a base set of food items (the hyperlinks in the crawled tree)
- Based on the dependency parsing on your new data, you can keep
  enriching the base data. For example: if 'butter' exists in your
  corpus, and 'peanut butter' is a frequently encountered pair of
  tokens, then 'peanut' and 'peanut butter' also get added to the
  corpus.
- The corpus can be maintained in a file which can be loaded in memory
  while processing, or database like redis,aerospike etc.
- Make sure you work with normalized i.e. small cased, special
  characters cleaned, words lemmatized/stemmed, both in corpus and the
  processing data. That would increase your coverage and accuracy.

Comment: This is a beautiful Answer! Made me visit @DhruvPathak's profile :)

Answer (score 4):

First extract all Noun phrases using NLTK's Chunking (code copied from [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/lukewrites/NP_chunking_with_nltk/blob/master/NP_chunking_with_the_NLTK.ipynb)):

```
import nltk
import re
import pprint
from nltk import Tree
import pdb


patterns="""
    NP: {<JJ>*<NN*>+}
    {<JJ>*<NN*><CC>*<NN*>+}
    {<NP><CC><NP>}
    {<RB><JJ>*<NN*>+}
    """

NPChunker = nltk.RegexpParser(patterns)

def prepare_text(input):
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(input)
    sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences] 
    sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in sentences]
    sentences = [NPChunker.parse(sent) for sent in sentences]
    return sentences


def parsed_text_to_NP(sentences):
    nps = []
    for sent in sentences:
        tree = NPChunker.parse(sent)
        print(tree)
        for subtree in tree.subtrees():
            if subtree.label() == 'NP':
                t = subtree
                t = ' '.join(word for word, tag in t.leaves())
                nps.append(t)
    return nps


def sent_parse(input):
    sentences = prepare_text(input)
    nps = parsed_text_to_NP(sentences)
    return nps



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sent_parse('I ate peanut butter and beef burger and a cup of coffee for breakfast.'))
```

This will POS tag your sentences and uses a regex parser to extract Noun Phrases.

**1.Define and Refine your noun phrase regex**

You'll need to change the **patterns** regex to define and refine your Noun phrases.
For example  is telling the parser than an NP followed by a coordinator (CC) like ''and'' and another NP is itself an NP.

**2.Change from NLTK POS tagger to Stanford POS tagger**

Also I noted that NLTK's POS tagger is not performing very well (e.g. It considers *had peanut* as a verb phrase. You can change the POS tagger to Stanford Parser if you want.

**3.Remove smaller noun phrases:**

After you have extracted all the Noun phrases for a sentence, you can remove the ones that are part of a bigger noun phrase. For example in the following example *beef burger* and *peanut butter* should be removed because
they're a part of a bigger noun phrase *peanut butter and beef burger*.

**4.Remove noun phrases which none of the words are in a food lexicon**

you will get noun phrases like *school bus*. if none of school and bus is in a food lexicon that you can compile from Wikipedia or WordNet then you remove the noun phrase. In this case remove *cup* and *breakfast* because they're not **hopefully** in your food lexicon.

The current code returns

```
['peanut butter and beef burger', 'peanut butter', 'beef burger', 'cup', 'coffee', 'breakfast']
```

for input

```
print(sent_parse('I ate peanut butter and beef burger and a cup of coffee for breakfast.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Too much for a comment, but not really an answer:

I think you would at least get closer if when you got two foods without a proper separator and combined them into one food.  That would give peanut butter, jelly sandwich, coffee.

**If** you have correct English you could detect **this** case by count/non-count.  Correcting the original to "I had **a** peanut butter and jelly sandwich and a cup of coffee for breakfast".  **Butter** is non-count, you can't have "a butter", but you can have "a sandwich".  Thus the **a** must apply to sandwich and despite the and "peanut butter" and "jelly sandwich" must be the same item--"peanut butter and jelly sandwich".  Your mistaken sentence would parse the other way, though!

I would be very surprised if you could come up with general rules that cover every case, though.  I would come at this sort of thing figuring that a few would leak and need a database to catch.

Answer (score 1):

You could search for n-grams in your text where you vary the value of n.  For example, if n=5 then you would extract "peanut butter and jelly sandwich" and "cup of coffee for breakfast", depending on where you start your search in the text for groups of five words.  You won't need a corpus of text or a database to make the algorithm work.

Answer (score 1):

A rule based approach with a lexicon of all food items would work here.

You can use GATE for the same and use JAPE rules with it.

In the above example your jape rule would have a condition to find all (np cc np) && np in "FOOD LEIXCON"

Can share a detailed jape code in an event you plan to go this route.